# rbenv install 2.7.1でエラー: mkdir: cannot create directory '/usr/local/rbenv/versions': Permission denied

Tags: ruby, centos, rbenv

CentOS 7での環境でRuby、及びRailsのインストールをしたいと思っているのですが、うまくいきません。

インストールの途中で作業を中断したせいか、何か余計なファイルができてしまったのかもしれません。

下記がエラー内容になります。

```sh
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ rbenv install 2.7.1
Downloading ruby-2.7.1.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.7/ruby-2.7.1.tar.bz2
Installing ruby-2.7.1...
mkdir: cannot create directory '/usr/local/rbenv/versions': Permission denied

BUILD FAILED (CentOS Linux 7 using ruby-build 20200401)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20200425104357.15616.hMCHV3
Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20200425104357.15616.log

Last 10 log lines:
/tmp/ruby-build.20200425104357.15616.hMCHV3 ~
/tmp/ruby-build.20200425104357.15616.hMCHV3/ruby-2.7.1 /tmp/ruby-build.20200425104357.15616.hMCHV3 ~
```

この内容によると、おそらく「`/tmp/ruby-build.20200424224509.11267.eBUEN2`というものを
クリーンアップして」ということかと思いますが、調べても自分ではクリーンアップの方法がわかりませんでした。

Ruby、及びRailsをダウンロードするにはどうすればいいでしょうか？

---

**追記**
以下のようにしてみましたが、同じエラーになります。

```sh
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ /usr/local/rbenv/bin/rbenv
rbenv 1.1.2-30-gc879cb0
Usage: rbenv <command> [<args>]

Some useful rbenv commands are:
   commands    List all available rbenv commands
   local       Set or show the local application-specific Ruby version
   global      Set or show the global Ruby version
   shell       Set or show the shell-specific Ruby version
   install     Install a Ruby version using ruby-build
   uninstall   Uninstall a specific Ruby version
   rehash      Rehash rbenv shims (run this after installing executables)
   version     Show the current Ruby version and its origin
   versions    List installed Ruby versions
   which       Display the full path to an executable
   whence      List all Ruby versions that contain the given executable

See 'rbenv help <command>' for information on a specific command.
For full documentation, see: https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#readme

[vagrant@localhost ~]$ echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ . ~/.bashrc
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ rbenv install 2.7.1
Downloading ruby-2.7.1.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.7/ruby-2.7.1.tar.bz2
Installing ruby-2.7.1...
mkdir: cannot create directory '/usr/local/rbenv/versions': Permission denied

BUILD FAILED (CentOS Linux 7 using ruby-build 20200401)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20200425144427.16489.ZFZUgA
Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20200425144427.16489.log

Last 10 log lines:
/tmp/ruby-build.20200425144427.16489.ZFZUgA ~
/tmp/ruby-build.20200425144427.16489.ZFZUgA/ruby-2.7.1 /tmp/ruby-build.20200425144427.16489.ZFZUgA ~
```

`sudo /usr/local/rbenv/bin/rbenv install` の実行結果は以下の通りです。

```sh
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo /usr/local/rbenv/bin/rbenv install 2.7.1
rbenv: no such command `install'
```

---

**追記2（rbenvのアンインストールのためにやったこと）**

1. rbenvのバージョンを確認

```sh
[vagrant@localhost .rbenv]$ rbenv -v
rbenv 1.1.2-30-gc879cb0
```

2. アンインストールを試すがそんなバージョンはないと言われる

```sh
[vagrant@localhost .rbenv]$ rbenv uninstall 1.1.2-30-gc879cb0
rbenv: version `1.1.2-30-gc879cb0' not installed
[vagrant@localhost .rbenv]$ rbenv uninstall 1.1.2
rbenv: version `1.1.2' not installed
```

3. 下記のコマンドを試してみる

```sh
[vagrant@localhost .rbenv]$ rm -rf `rbenv root`
[vagrant@localhost .rbenv]$
```

4. うまく行ったのかと思い、ヴァージョンを確かめるもまだ存在している

```sh
[vagrant@localhost .rbenv]$ rbenv -v
rbenv 1.1.2-30-gc879cb0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

root 権限が無いと書きこめない場所に書きこもうとしてエラーになっています。自分用に使いたいだけであれば rbenv は root 権限が無くても諸々を管理できるように設定するのが便利ですし、そちらの方が一般的かと思います。rbenv を一度アンインストールして、sudo せずにインストールするのは如何でしょうか。

rbenv をどのようにインストールされたのか分からないのでアンインストール方法はお任せします。

アンインストール後、[rbenv の README.md](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) に従ってインストールしてください。"Basic GitHub Checkout" と書かれているやり方です。

以下に実行するであろうコマンドの列を書いておきますが、これをこのままコピペするのではなく、README.md の説明を読みつつやるのをオススメします。

```
git clone https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv
cd ~/.rbenv && src/configure && make -C src
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc  # あるいは ~/.bash_profile
~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv init
# ↑表示された出力に従う
# シェルを再起動する
mkdir -p "$(rbenv root)"/plugins
git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git "$(rbenv root)"/plugins/ruby-build
```

このあと `rbenv install ほにゃらら` をすると色々エラーが出るかもしれません。その多くは依存しているバイナリやライブラリが足りないことに起因しています。エラーログを読んで足りないものを yum からインストールしてください。場合によっては "Results logged to ほにゃらら" と書かれているログファイルを読む必要があるでしょう。

たとえば下のあたりが必要そうです。

```
yum install wget git gcc autoconf make bzip2 openssl-devel
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。自分なりに調べて追記文のようにアンインストールを試してみたのですが
アンインストール自体うまくいきません。上にアンインストールをするためにした自分のコマンドを記載したのですが、どこが間違っているかわかりますでしょうか？（もしくはコマンド全体が間違っておりますでしょうか？）

Comment: @ligtning rbenv をインストールした方法が分からないので何とも言えません。

Comment: @ligtning rbenv 自体をアンインストールするには `sudo rm -rf \`rbenv root\`` でインストール先のディレクトリを削除するだけです。[README](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#uninstalling-rbenv) にも解説があります。 / `rbenv uninstall ...` は rbenv 経由でインストールした **Rubyの削除** に使用するコマンドなので、rbenv 自体は削除できません。

Comment: @cubick たとえば rbenv を更に他のパッケージマネジャーでインストールしてしまった場合はそうとも限らないのではないでしょうか……？　`/usr/local` 下にあるので多分違うんだろうなとは思いつつ、まずはインストール方法を聞きたかった次第です。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
一度Centos7の環境を再度作り直しました。
現在コマンドは下記のようになっております。
すいません、前回は訳がわからず作業していたので
インストールした方法が分からない状態に陥ってしまいました。
申し訳ないのですがこちらは一旦締め切らせていただき、新たに下記のリンクで最初からRuby及びRailsのインストール方法を教えていただくことは可能でしょうか？
もしよろしければ何卒よろしくお願い申し上げます。

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/65998/vagrant%e3%81%a8centos7%e7%92%b0%e5%a2%83%e4%b8%8b%e3%81%a7ruby%e5%8f%8a%e3%81%b3rails%e3%82%92%e3%82%a4%e3%83%b3%e3%82%b9%e3%83%88%e3%83%bc%e3%83%ab%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84

Answer (score 3):

事前に `rbenv` を root 権限でインストールしていませんか？ `/usr/local/rbenv/` 以下にインストールされているようなので、この状態であるなら Ruby のインストールにも root 権限が必要となります。

具体的には `sudo` コマンドを使用する必要があると思います。

```
$ sudo rbenv install 2.7.1
```

---

あなたは rbenv を一般ユーザーの権限で実行していますが、以下のエラーは対象のディレクトリに対して "適切な権限が無い (ファイルが作成できない)" という内容です。

```
mkdir: cannot create directory '/usr/local/rbenv/versions': Permission denied
```

対象のディレクトリ `/usr` を含め、システムディレクトリに対して変更を加えるには Linux だと管理者 (root) 権限が必要になります。
root ユーザーでログインする代わりに、通常は `sudo` コマンドを使用するのが一般的です。

---

**追記**

`/usr/local/rbenv/` 以下にインストールされているなら、`rbenv` コマンドは恐らく以下のパスで呼び出す必要があります。

```
/usr/local/rbenv/bin/rbenv
```

環境変数 PATH に追加しておくと便利でしょう。

```
$ echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
$ . ~/.bashrc
```

環境変数 PATH の設定を含め、rbenv の使い方に関しては [README](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) にも記載があるので、今一度確認してみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。自分もそう思ってsudo rbenv install 2.7.1のコマンド、もしくは消してみようと思って、[vagrant@localhost ~]$ rm -fr ~/.rbenv/versions/1.1.2-30-gc879cb0 [vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo rbenv rehashというコマンドをやってみたのですが、どちらのコマンドもsudo: rbenv: command not foundという風に出ます。これは他に何か足りていないのでしょうか？

Comment: 回答に追記しましたので確認してみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。追記のようにやってみましたが、やはりRubyのインストールができないようです。。。

Comment: 回答の本文に既に記載した通り、`sudo rbenv install 2.7.1` のように実行してください。質問に追記された内容では当初と同じまま `sudo` を付けないで実行しているためエラーになっています。

Comment: ありがとうございます。[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo rbenv install 2.7.1
sudo: rbenv: command not foundのようにsudoをつけるとコマンドが見つからないと出てしまいます。。。

Comment: `sudo /usr/local/rbenv/bin/rbenv install 2.7.1` と実行するとどうなりますか？

Comment: [vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo /usr/local/rbenv/bin/rbenv install 2.7.1
rbenv: no such command `install'
と表示されます。

Answer (score -1):

> mkdir: cannot create directory '/usr/local/rbenv/versions': Permission denied

問題はこれでは

Comment: ありがとうございます。私もそう思うのですが
具体的に何をしていいのかわかっていません。
そのエラーの下に
Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20200425104357.15616.hMCHV3

とあるのでこちらをクリーンアップしないといけないのかと思い調べているのですが
解決策が見つかりません。。。